# Probability mass function from two random discrete variables in the same set

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be random discrete variables, both of which take values in set $\{1,2,3...\}$, and let $p_1$ and $p_2$ donate their probability mass function respectively. 
show that $c\, p_1+(1-c)\,p_2$ is a pmf given that $c \in [0,1]$.

Comment: How do you define a pmf?

Comment: What steps have you taken and where are you getting stuck, Lauren?

Comment: I literally dont know where to begin. I understand the PMF is the sum of all values in the set adding to 1, any tips where to go from here?

Comment: You just answered it yourself. Write out the sum of all values in the set of the convex combination, and check whether it equals, it too, unity. $c$ is constant so it is a common factor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a probability mass function (pmf) it is expected that it takes nonnegative values on a countable set and that the summation of these values equals $1$. The function $p=cp_{1}+\left(1-c\right)p_{2}$ satisfies these conditions if $c\in\left[0,1\right]$.